# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' being thrown before pages load

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm getting the 'System.OutOfMemoryException' on all of my asp.net pages before they open. These pages aren't executing any code that would throw this error (Page_Load is empty for all these pages). What could be causing this to happen?

Stack Trace:

```
[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence     assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence  assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName,    Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +83
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +126
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +62
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +160
System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +93
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Either you're running on a system with 16MB of RAM, or your code is doing something.  Check for a global.asax file, and check all code-behind pages for code that could be causing it.

Comment: Although you haven't given much detail about your problem. You may find this link helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1450516.aspx. Without code or even a detailed description of how the problem came about, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: So it turns out the problem wasn't my applications; some other applications on the same server weren't releasing memory which was causing my pages to throw the error.