# Worker process not releasing memory and Oracle connection not closing

Tags: vb.net, oracle, iis

I have an issue where my .NET 3.5 applications are causing the IIS worker process to continually eat up memory and never release it until the applications start throwing memory related errors and I have to recycle the IIS worker process. Another thing I've noticed is that the connection to the Oracle DB server also doesn't close and will remain open until I recycle the IIS worker process (as far as I can tell I'm closing the Oracle connections properly). From what I've read in other similar posts the GC is supposed to clean up unused memory and allow it to be reallocated but this is quite clearly not happening here (I'm observing the same problem on both the remote host and local host. I'm going to assume that this isn't an issue related to IIS settings but rather that I'm not doing proper housecleaning in my code; what things should I be look at? Thanks.

Here is my code related to querying the Oracle DB:

```
 Using conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)

        Try

            cmd.Connection = conn
            daData = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
            cbData = New OracleCommandBuilder(daData)
            dtData = New DataTable()
            dtDADPLIs = New DataTable()
            conn.Open()

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE" _                                       

            daData.Fill(dtData)

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE2"

            daData.Fill(dtDADPLIs)
            QueryName = "SD_TIER_REPORT"
            WriteQueryLog(QueryName)

        Catch ex As OracleException

            'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())

        Finally

            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
```

Comment: Are you implementing the `using(OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection()) {...}` syntactic sugar in your apps to dispose the connection object after it's been closed? Can you show us how you're code typically opens a connection and then closes/disposes of it.

Comment: Also when asking questions like this, can you specify Windows/IIS version and where relevant your application pool configuration.

Comment: I'm using windows XP with IIS 5.1. I've added the Oracle connection code below

Comment: @StephenT: why don't you update your question with this code?

Comment: I can see you're using datatables. How many records do you plan to read? Is it a big buffer?

Comment: Can you add this code to your question. Also see @LeftyX's comment above. You need to tell us more about your server spec - how much memory it has, what the app pool tops out at before you have to recycle. How many concurrent users and typical load when this happens.

Comment: Is this question related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662925/system-outofmemoryexception-being-thrown-before-pages-load ?

Comment: @Leftyx: I've updated the question, sorry. It can load up to 200k records into the datatable which pushes the worker process memory up to about 1GB.

Comment: You know that you don't need to have that `Finally` block there, it's redundant because the `Using` statement will automatically call `conn.Dispose()` and close the connection and dispose it.

Comment: Why are you loading 200k records all at once? That is sure to be why you're running out of memory.

Comment: How much memory does your workstation have?

Comment: @Kev: For certain reports there really isn't a way around it; the application is generating reports based on an account selected by the user and I can't parse it into smaller bits. Furthermore the initial query is pulling from a 6M+ record table...if I tried to break it into smaller datasets wouldn't the multiple queries against the large master table slow the application down significantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I ran into the same issue and I bumped into this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/02/14/73033.aspx) and this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/02/20/77422.aspx).
I exchanged a few emails with the author (Paul Wilson) and he helped me to understand the problem with large objects which are allocated in memory in a "**Large Object Heap**" and it never gets compacted.

This is what he told me:

> Larger objects are indeed allocated separately, where large is
>   something around 60-90 KB or larger (I don't remember exactly, and its
>   not officially documented anyhow).  So if your byte arrays, and other
>   objects for that matter, are larger than that threshold then they will
>   be allocated separately.  When does the large object heap get
>   collected?  You may have ran into statements about there being several
>   generations of normal memory allocation (0, 1, and 2 in the current
>   frameworks) -- well the large object heap is basically considered to
>   be generation 2 automatically.  That means that it will not be
>   collected until there isn't enough memory left after collecting gen 0
>   and gen 1 -- so basically it only happens on a full GC collection.  So
>   to answer your question -- there is no way to make sure objects in the
>   large object heap get collected any sooner.   The problem is that I'm
>   talking about garbage collection, which assumes that your objects
>   (large objects in this case) are no longer referenced anywhere and
>   thus available to be collected.  If they are still referenced
>   somewhere, then it simply doesn't matter how much the GC runs -- your
>   memory usage is simply going to go up and up.  So do you have all
>   references gone?  It may seem you do, and you might be right -- all I
>   can tell you is that its very easy to be wrong, and its a terrible
>   amount of work with memory profilers and no shortcuts to prove it one
>   way or the other.  I can tell you that if a manual GC.Collect reliably
>   does reduce your memory usage, then you've obviously got your objects
>   de-referenced -- else a GC.Collect wouldn't help.  So the question may
>   simply be what makes you think you are having a memory problem?  There
>   may be no reason for a GC to collect memory if you have plenty
>   available on a big server system!

Another article which is worth reading is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET).

Solution?

1. Fetch only data you need
2. Avoid using datasets when possible and choose a datareader.

UPDATE:

If you're using a reporting tool like **MS ReportViewer** if you can bind your report to a "business object".